# Creating a table by using multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am writing a code that creates new element of an array every time it runs. Does anybody have any suggestions on how I would then add that to element to a table in an html? I am using the push command to create new array elements. So every time that I go through an if loop. Each of the three arrays has a new element I am also trying to put three arrays into one table. Each array represents a column. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
var xcoordinates = [];
var ycoordinates = [];
var counter = [];
    i = 0,
    slide = $("#slide");

    slide.click(function (e) {
        if (i < (images.length + i)) {
            slide.attr("src", images[i++]);
            counter(i)
            xcoordinates.push(e.pageX);
            ycoordinates.push(e.pageY);
        }
    }).trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: just add the table modification code after your `.push()` calls...

Comment: You've got really strange condition there, which in my opinion will never be `true`.